# why did my fluid change into multi colored spheres?

Tags: fluid-simulation

[image]

the fluid mesh is under there but it's surrounded by these spheres

Comment: Those aren't spheres, they are the particles getting simulated. Looks like your scale quite small. Perhaps increasing the size of something or decreasing the particle render size would help.

Comment: @NascentSpace well changing the size of anything is not an option because that screws up all the rigs in the scene

Comment: Could always just turn off overlays to view your fluid I guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spheres are the particles of the fluid simulation and their size can be controlled via the Viewport Display properties in the Liquid particle settings.

[image: Particle Viewport Display settings]

Changing the Size to 0 will result in point particles instead of spheres.

Alternatively, you can hide them completely by disabling the visibility settings alongside the particle system in the list :

[image: disable particle system visibility]